# Time complexity of integer comparison in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of integer comparison in Python for very large integers? For example, if we calculate factorial of 1000 using 2 functions, then check equality, is it O(1)?

```
def fact(n):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(n):
        prod = prod * (i + 1)
    return prod

i = fact(1000)
j = fact(1000)

# Complexity of this check?
if i == j:
    print "Equal"
```

Comment: With my python 2.7.12, I have an error : RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @Louis check it here: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_6wTA8XtBGQ_0.py

Comment: @ayushgp CodeSkulpter is not is it's own Python implementation. It was made specifically for the use of a course at Rice university. It doesn't behave like CPython, the usual Python, hence why people will be getting "maximum recursion depth" errors because of your code

Comment: I've edited the code to solely focus on the question I've asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer, but the answer is nevertheless obvious ;-)

That is, if two integers are in fact equal, it's impossible to *know* that without comparing all their bits.  So in case of equality, the time needed is proportional to the number of bits (which is proportional to `log(abs(N))` if `N` is one of the comparands).

If they're not in fact equal, there are several cases, all related to implementation internals.  Long ints are stored as a vector of "digits" in a power-of-2 base.  If the vectors don't have the same lengths, then the ints aren't equal, and *that* takes constant time.

But if they do have the same lengths, then the "digits" have to be compared until finding the first (if any) mismatching pair.  That takes time proportional to the number of digits that need to be compared.

Then complicate all the above to account for possible mixtures of signs.

Comment: It's not really clear what the N you're talking about is and you seem to be saying the comparison is O(N) and O(logN) at the same time. It sounds like there's a right answer in there somewhere, maybe easier if you just take on the specific case, 1000! == 1000!

Comment: If you''re comparing `N == M` and they're equal, then the time needed is proportional to `log(abs(N))` - proportional to the number of bits needed to express `N`.  If they're not equal, read the answer again ;-)

Comment: Why is the the sequential, exhaustive comparison of two identical zillion-long sequences of bits O(log(zillion))?

Comment: It isn't.  If you have two equal zillion-long sequences of bits, it will take a zillion bit comparisons to know that.  But if you're comparing two ints each equal to a zillion, then then only `log2(zillion)` bit comparisons are needed.

Comment: @TimPeters ok, N being the number itself, which is what I was trying to get you to clarify.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 'time complexity of comparison of sequences' is a reasonable question as is 'worst case performance' which happens to be when the sequences are identical.