# Time complexity for comparing two numbers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to establish the time complexity of an algorithm that involves comparison of numbers.

Say I have two numbers A and B, where both numbers have N number of digits individually. Assume it also holds that A<=K and B<=K.

Now I want to compare if A<=B (if A is less than or equal to B).

I suspect that the time complexity is either O(N) or O(K).

What is the correct time complexity?

Comment: You should have a look in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061819/1625253 They are talking about python, but I think you can see it in general.

Comment: You should also have a look here -> https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/comparing-two-products-of-lists-of-integers

Comment: yes @inson, it depends on language and underlaying interpreter and if you you do it by yourself or use the implemented comparison methods in the specific language.

Comment: It depends on your abstract machine model, the answer for a RAM machine  than for a PRAM machine. Integer comparison is in NC.

Comment: If it's linear complexity, you should be able to say it's O(n), whether n is derived from N, K, or any optimization based on the number of bits used to represent them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that A, B <= K doesn't really help.

You can conclude by comparing all digits left-to-right, until you find a difference, and this takes at worst O(N) comparisons. This is optimal as you have to look at that many digits (at worst).

You can also observe that N = O(Log K).

Comment: Well, i don't agree here `and this takes at worst O(N) comparisons` because in the best-case if you have matching strings then it will take `N` steps where `N` is either the length of A or B.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: The best case would be of sign mismatch where you would know right away which number is bigger (or smaller). Equality is not the best case scenario for this problem.

Comment: @displayName The basic rule in Turing machines theory says that you need at `least N steps where N is length of string` to decide whether a string belongs to a language or not. Y

Comment: Coming to your point. This is not worst-case. Worst-case in this scenario is associated with a fail that is: You have `n-1` integers same in both A and B and Nth integer is different , that's the worst-case in this problem

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: what is all this nonsense ? The best case is O(1) and the worst case O(N), that's it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Where is non-sense? Suppose length of A = 2 and length of B = 3 then you need atleast 2 steps and this is not O(1) , this is a counter example. It's O(n) where n < m and n is length of A and m is length of B.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: I am not sure you understand the meaning of best case vs. worst case. The best case is O(1). And the length of A and B are known to be N, there is no M.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people are suggesting you to look at numerous answers. In your case, the complexity is clearly O(N).

First you compare the signs - if they differ, you know the higher number and the lower number.

If the signs are same, you start from the most significant digit of both numbers and if at any place the digit differs, you can figure out which number is bigger than the other.

In case the numbers are negative, the larger most significant digit will imply that the number is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple subtraction when you compare two numbers with the same sign? The Brent-Kung (prefix) adder adds (subtracts) two n-bit operands in O(lg n) time. (Think of your numbers having $n$ bits rather than N digits in decimal, and use a 2's complement operation to perform subtraction by addition.) For positive operands, if the difference comes out to be negative, the sign bit will tell you which one is greater or smaller. For example if you compare 8 against 5 by subtracting 5 from 8, the sign bit of their difference, i.e., 8-5 will be 0 indicating that 8 is greater than 5. If you compare 5 against 8 by subtracting 8 from 5 then the sign bit of the difference will be 1, indicating that 5 is smaller than 8. If you compare -8 against -5 by subtracting -5 from -8, i.e., -8 - (-5) = -3, the sign bit of the difference will be 1 indicating that -8 is smaller than -5. If you compare -5 against -8 by subtracting -8 from -5, i.e., -5 - (-8) = 3, the sign bit of the difference will be 0 indicating that -5 is greater than -8.

To sum up,

(i) If a and b are two positive numbers or two negative numbers, a sign bit of 0 of difference a-b asserts that a is greater than $b$ and a sign bit of 1 of the same difference asserts that a is less than b.

(ii) If they have opposite signs, the one with the negative sign is obviously smaller than the other one.

(iii) If a and b are n-bit numbers then the time complexity is O(lg n).