# Why is this list comprehension slower than initializing conditionally using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

Why is initializing the diagonal in a 2d matrix using an external loop much faster than doing it in a list comprehension? I was using the list comprehension and I was getting time limit exceeded in Leetcode in [a problem involving dynamic programming](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/). I thought my algorithm was wrong. Switching to an external loop solved it in half the time and my solution got accepted. Here is sample of my code with timing. The first one is 6 times slower than the second approach on my machine.

```
#super slow
from time import perf_counter
s=perf_counter()
dpArray=[[  True if i==j else False for j in range(1000)] for i in range(1000) ]
print(f"Initialized in {perf_counter() - s:0.4f} seconds")

#super fast
s=perf_counter()
dpArray=[[False]*1000 for i in range(1000) ]
for i in range(1000):
    dpArray[i][i]=True
print(f"Initialized diagonal in {perf_counter() - s:0.4f} seconds")
```

```
Execution:
Initialized in 0.0645 seconds
Initialized diagonal in 0.0095 seconds
```

Incase anyone is interested in the solution,
here is the slow version, which barely passes. I had to make a few tweaks to avoid a TLE error:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        dp = [[  True if i==j else False for j in range(len(s))] for i in range(len(s)) ]
        ans=s[0]
        for j in range(len(s)):
            for i in (range(j)):
                if s[i]==s[j] and (dp[i+1][j-1] or j==i+1):
                    dp[i][j]=True
                    if j-i+1>len(ans):
                        ans=s[i:j+1]
        return ans
```

Fast version:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        dp = [[False]*len(s) for _ in range(len(s)) ]
        for i in range(len(s)):
            dp[i][i]=True
        ans=s[0]
        for j in range(len(s)):
            for i in range(j):
                if s[i]==s[j] and (dp[i+1][j-1] or j==i+1):
                    dp[i][j]=True
                    if j-i+1>len(ans):
                        ans=s[i:j+1]
        return ans
```

Comment: @Onyambu: Both versions have O(n^2) complexity. The second one still has to create dpArray.

Comment: @Onyambu In fact the complexity of the second one is slightly higher as `[False]*1000` is also `O(n)`, but the overheads are different.

Comment: Sidenote: `True if <boolean> else False` is equivalent to `<boolean>`. Actually, maybe this isn't a sidenote if the conditional expression adds additional overhead.

Comment: @Selcuk Yeah after testing a bit, it's negligible in comparison to the difference in the loops, if at all.

Comment: BTW, are you allowed to use NumPy in Leetcode? I think I found the equivalent solution and it's 60 times faster: `a = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=np.bool_); np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)`

Comment: @wjandrea LeetCode does support NumPy. I think `np.eye(1000, dtype=bool)` is also equivalent. Though given the usual "incremental" process of dynamic programming (i. e., they probably afterwards process the matrix one element at a time based on some check and the element left/above or so), I somewhat doubt NumPy will end up faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy Updated the post with the link. Thought the problem is not relevant as I was more curious about why a simple loop initialization can lead to TLE error. I will post my solutions too here so other can try them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are not equivalent. In the list comprehension you perform 1,000,000 comparisons (`if i==j`) while in the second one you don't have any comparisons at all.

Also `[False]*1000` is a built-in shortcut and probably executes faster than a for loop.

Note that the time complexity for both methods is `O(n^2)`, but that doesn't mean that one cannot be faster than the other.

Comment: Accepting this answer. Still it is a bit hard to believe a simple if condition can double the execution time of a solution :) given the time complexity is same in both cases.

Comment: Note that comparing two integers is not a small feat. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061735/time-complexity-of-integer-comparison-in-python/44061819#44061819) by Tim Peters, a core Python developer. Complexity doesn't say much about the execution speed. It only says that the time will probably quadruple in both cases if you double N.

Comment: @Selcuk They only have ints from 0 to 999, though, that's a single "digit". It's not that different from the comparison in `s[i]==s[j]` that they do in the second part of their solution, and that one additionally has to look up the two "letters". Let alone the `(dp[i+1][j-1] or j==i+1)` that might follow.

Comment: @KellyBundy Right. The code was completely different before the edit, see edit history.

Comment: Right, although the singledigitness was there from the start (and the additional code was [predictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893032/why-is-this-list-comprehension-slower-than-initializing-conditionally-using-a-fo?noredirect=1#comment123555515_69893032) :-)

Comment: @Suneel Well you have another per-cell condition in your remaining code, and that runs only for half of the matrix (the "upper-right triangle") whereas your initialization does the whole square matrix.